# How to have a favorites button Add a card to a seperate page called favorites.html

Tags: javascript, java, html, local-storage, materialize

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m6">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
      <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this code where I want to have the button add this card to a separate page called favorites.html. When the user clicks the add button it will also add the cards to the favorites.html page. So the user will have the main index.html page that displays these cards and then they can navigate to the favorites.html page to view the collection of favorites.  How would I go about doing this? I tried to link the add button to the "favorites.html" page but it did not add the card to it.

Comment: i had understand what you want to ask....

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the favourite cards somewhere, ideally I would say use a Database, but if your project does not have a database yet, the easiest way to do it is to use local storage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You'll definitely need to add some javascript in your site.

I'll let you some links here, and an example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#value

### Example

```js
function onAddButtonClick() {
  // This function will get excecuted whne you click the Add button
  localStorage.setItem('favouriteCard', 'MockText');
}

function onFavouriteViewLoad() {
  // You can get this function excecuted when you load the favourite.html page
  // to get what you want to show.
  return localStorage.getItem('favouriteCard');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        <button onClick="onAddButtonClick()" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```